# I'm using migLayout and it added a very strange space above the panel

Tags: java, jpanel, miglayout

https://i.stack.imgur.com/CTe0k.jpg

So in the image above I have a two panel selector thing going. The panel on the right uses migLayout, and I can't figure out why there is that space above the right panel.

even what I simply have this.setLayout(new MigLayout("", "", ""));

anyone know what I can do to fix this?

Comment: If you still have the problem. Provide more code so we can help you. I don't think it has something to do with MigLayout rather the way the panel with MigLayout is added to the main frame.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue, but I found a solution:

```
MigLayout mainLayout = new MigLayout("insets 0");
```